# Crossing Out Rows & Columns of Matrix for det

Tags: matrices

What would be the best way to produce something similar to the image below, including the circle and lines through the row and column of that pivot?  I'd settle even for just the lines.

[image: Determinant]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `pstricks`. Note it can be compiled with `pdflatex`, if it is launched with the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX).

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\[  \begin{postscript}
  \psset{linecolor=IndianRed, framesep = 1pt,  nodesepB=-2.2ex}
  \begin{vmatrix}
    \circlenode{P}{12 } & 5                          & \Rnode{L}{6}            \\
    - 2                 & -3                         & -6\pnode[1pt,  9pt]{M1} \\%
    \Rnode{C}{5}        & \pnode[-1pt,  -2pt]{M2} -7 & 3
    \psframe(M1)(M2)
    \ncline{P}{L}
    \ncline{P}{C}
  \end{vmatrix}
  \qquad\psset{linecolor=SteelBlue}
  \begin{vmatrix}
    \Rnode{L1}{12}      & \circlenode{P}{5} & \Rnode{L2}{6}      \\
    \Rnode{M1}{\,- 2\,} & -3                & \Rnode{N1}{\,-6\,} \\%
    \Rnode{M2}{5}       & \Rnode{C}{-7}     & \Rnode{N2}{3}
    \ncbox[nodesep=0.6ex,  boxsize=1.7ex]{M1}{M2}\ncbox[nodesep=0.6ex,  boxsize=1.7ex]{N1}{N2}
    \ncline{P}{L1} \ncline{P}{L2}
    \ncline{P}{C}
  \end{vmatrix}
  \qquad\psset{linecolor=DarkSeaGreen,  nodesepB=-2.4ex}
  \begin{vmatrix}
    \Rnode{L}{12}             & 5                        & \circlenode{P}{6} \\
    \pnode[-1pt,  9pt]{M1}- 2 & -3                       & -6                \\%
    5                         & -7\pnode[2pt,  -3pt]{M2} & \Rnode{C}{3}
    \psframe(M1)(M2)
    \ncline{P}{L}
    \ncline{P}{C}
  \end{vmatrix}
  \end{postscript} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `nicematrix` and TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{vNiceMatrix}[margin=0.5em]
  12 & 5  & 6 \\
  -2 & \Block[draw=red]{2-2}{}
        -3 & -6 \\
  5  & -7 & 3 
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [red]
  \draw (1-1) circle (2.2mm) ; 
  \draw (1.5-|1) -- (1.5-|4) ; 
  \draw (1-|1.5) -- (4-|1.5) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{vNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]